# Transposing Data - Easier Way to Add Additional Columns to Perl Script

Tags: perl

I have a perl scrip below that does a fantastic job, however, I how want to perform the same task but on a larger file. The script below is designed for use on a file containing 15 columns, of which data is transposed from 4 (12-15). I need to extend this to columns 12-2550. Is there an easier way of doing this other than manually adding additional if statements?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl5.8.6 -w

$input = "Baillie.txt";
$output = "Baillie_edited.txt";


open OUTPUT_FILE_HANDLE, ">$output";
close OUTPUT_FILE_HANDLE;
open OUTPUT_FILE_HANDLE, ">>$output";

open INPUT_FILE_HANDLE, "<$input";

$counter = 1;
while (<INPUT_FILE_HANDLE>) {
#print $_;
chomp();
if ($counter == 1) {
    print OUTPUT_FILE_HANDLE "sample\t".$_."\n";
    @header = split /\t/, $_;
}
else {
    $orig_line = $_;
    @line = split /\t/, $_;
        if ($line[12] == 1|1 or $line[12] == 0|1 or $line[12] == 1|0) {
            print OUTPUT_FILE_HANDLE $header[12]."\t".$orig_line."\n";
        }
        if ($line[13] == 1|1 or $line[13] == 0|1 or $line[13] == 1|0) {
            print OUTPUT_FILE_HANDLE $header[13]."\t".$orig_line."\n";
        }
        if ($line[14] == 1|1 or $line[14] == 0|1 or $line[14] == 1|0) {
            print OUTPUT_FILE_HANDLE $header[14]."\t".$orig_line."\n";
        }
        if ($line[15] == 1|1 or $line[15] == 0|1 or $line[15] == 1|0) {
            print OUTPUT_FILE_HANDLE $header[15]."\t".$orig_line."\n";
        }
    }
}
#last if ($counter eq 100000);
$counter++;
close OUTPUT_FILE_HANDLE;
close INPUT_FILE_HANDLE;
exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :
Fisrt, always put after the *shebang* `use strict; use warnings;`. Then, use this for loop (adapt the logic to your needs) :

```
foreach my $count (12..2550) {
    if ($line[$count] == 1|0) {
        print OUTPUT_FILE_HANDLE $header[$count]."\t".$orig_line."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment when you cut the code. There's too much going on in this script that is strange... `0|1` is another thing (`0|1` is the same as both `1|0` and `1|1`, as far as I know). But accepting that the script "works", your solution correctly generalizes the operation to an extended range of columns.